# Implement fireworks thread inside oncreate method

Tags: android, multithreading, fireworks

I am trying to accomplish fireworks functionality based on the github code from [Lenoids](https://github.com/plattysoft/Leonids). I want to create two fireworks (one white and another red) and have them display continuously after every two seconds.

Here's what I did so far:

1. Created two buttons (one for each color of fireworks). The buttons have the fireworks functionality.
2. Call the buttons programatically in a thread  to display the fireworks.

   ```
        @Override
       protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
       super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
       setContentView(R.layout.activity_congratulations);

       new Thread(new Runnable() {
           @Override
           public void run() {
               while(true){
                   try {
                       Thread.sleep(100);
                       button10.callOnClick();  //for red fireworks 
                       button11.callOnClick();  //for white fireworks 
                   } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                       e.printStackTrace();
                   }


               }
           }
       }).start();
   }
   ```

The problem is that if I increase the value of sleep method, then the fireworks do not show up at all. How can I accomplish the two second continuous fireworks functionality?

Here's the fireworks code:

```
new ParticleSystem(MyClass.this, 100, R.drawable.star_pink, 800) .setSpeedRange(0.1f, 0.25f) .oneShot(view, 70);
```

Comment: What is the duration of fireworks in the lobrary you are using?

Comment: new ParticleSystem(MyClass.this, 100, R.drawable.star_pink, 800)
                                 .setSpeedRange(0.1f, 0.25f)
                                    .oneShot(view, 70);

There is no duration.

Comment: What value of sleep do not show the fireworks? 800ms is the duration of your fireworks. Using your thread above. You cannot show the fireworks if sleep value is greater or equal than 800

Comment: If I increase from 100 to any other value.

Comment: @ Malik Ahsan, any ideas?

Comment: If you want to run the firework every 2 seconds. Try using the handler instead of threads.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to run the firework every two seconds then use Handler instead of the thread and thread.sleep.

```
final Handler ha=new Handler();
ha.postDelayed(new Runnable() {

@Override
public void run() {
   button10.callOnClick();   
   button11.callOnClick();
    ha.postDelayed(this, 2000);
 }
}, 2000);
```

Hope that helps.